# Proxy SPRINGBOOT

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-applications, aop

i'm tryining to understand how to use proxy and aspect in springboot, is the first time that I use AOP and it's not easy.Someone can tell me if is it correct that code?
I'm not sure if the aspects should point to the proxy method.
Thanks

This my proxy code

```
package local.luddel;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ProxyOggetto {
    
    private InterfacciaOggetto interfacciaOggetto;

    public ProxyOggetto(InterfacciaOggetto interfacciaOggetto) {
        super();
        this.interfacciaOggetto = interfacciaOggetto;
    }
    
    
    public void getEccociOggetto() {
        System.out.println("Sono nel proxy");
        interfacciaOggetto.eccoci();
    }
    public void getCiaoOggetto() {
        System.out.println("Sono nel proxy");
        interfacciaOggetto.ciao();
    }
}
```

This is my Aspect class

```
package local.luddel;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {
    @Before(value = "execution(* local.luddel.ProxyOggetto.getEccociOggetto())")
    public void beforeEccoci() {
        System.out.println("Sono in asepct");
    }
}
```

This is my Config class with all the beans

```
package local.luddel;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class ConfigBean {
    
    @Bean(value = "oggetto")
    public Oggetto getOggetto() {
        return new Oggetto();
    }
    
    @Bean(value = "myAspect")
    public MyAspect getMyAspect() {
        return new MyAspect();
    }
    
    @Bean(value = "service")
    public Servizio getServizio(){
        return new Servizio();
    }
    @Bean(value = "proxy")
    public ProxyOggetto getProxyOggetto() {
        return new ProxyOggetto(getOggetto());
    }

}
```

This is my Main

```
package local.luddel;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        myBeanOggetto();
        

    }

    static public void myBeanOggetto() {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConfigBean.class);
        ProxyOggetto proxyOggetto = applicationContext.getBean("proxy", ProxyOggetto.class);
        proxyOggetto.getEccociOggetto();
    }
```

Comment: Does your code do what you expect when you run it?

Comment: Yes it does what i want.

I want understand if what i had write have sense or not.

Comment: Well, you said yourself that the code does what you want. It does make sense, even though with component scan active and `@Component` annotations on both the aspect and the target class, it is unnecessary to use additional `@Bean` factory methods. You can just erase them, and your code should still work.